# Kotlin transparent property resolver?

Tags: kotlin, delegation

Code is simpler than words:

```
data class Dim2(val x:Int , val y:Int)
data class Dim3(val dim2:Dim2 , val z:Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val v = Dim3(Dim2(1,2) , 3)
    println("value : x = ${v.dim2.x} , y = ${v.dim2.y} , z = ${v.z} ")
}
```

Because Kotlin advocates composition over of inheritance , so I compose `Dim2` into `Dim3`.

But in `Dim3` , accessing `Dim2`'s property is very ugly. Not so elegant as inheritance.

One way to solve this problem is this :

```
interface IDim2 {
    val x:Int
    val y:Int
}

interface IDim3 : IDim2 {
    val z:Int
} 

data class Dim2(override val x:Int , override val y:Int) : IDim2
data class Dim3(val dim2:Dim2 , override val z:Int) : IDim3 , IDim2 by dim2


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val v : IDim3 = Dim3(Dim2(1,2) , 3)
    println("value : x = ${v.x} , y = ${v.y} , z = ${v.z} ")
}
```

It works , but it is too overkill . All fields need to be extracted to interface.

Is there any better solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to add those properties is to use [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties):

```
data class Dim2(val x:Int , val y:Int)
data class Dim3(val dim2:Dim2 , val z:Int)

val Dim3.x: Int get() = dim2.x
val Dim3.y: Int get() = dim2.y
```

While this still requires some boilerplate code, it is more compact than the inheritance solution.

Comment: Do you think it would be good to have a way to delegate single properties in the standard library? So he could define `val x by PropertyDelegate(dim2::x)` e.g.

Comment: What if `Dim2` has a lot of properties ,  not just two like this example. Manually providing these delegation still looks cumbersome.

Comment: @s1m0nw1, well, it might be a good idea for `var`s, but it requires about the same amount of code for `val`s. Not quite sure about whether we need this in the standard library, is there a feature request or a discussion for that?

Comment: @smallufo, I agree, but I don't know about a more concise way. Though I think it's possible to generate these properties with an annotation processor.

Comment: @hotkey that’s true... vals is not useful. I’ve seen someone asking for it here a few weeks back, don’t know about a feature request that covers it though